# CMake Error - Could NOT find BLAS - when trying to use CMake to build PyMultiNest

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm new to linux/ubuntu and so I'm a bit lost at how to fix this problem.

I'm trying to install some software and everything I install seems to require me to install something else to have the previous install work!

[Right now I'm following this set of instructions](https://johannesbuchner.github.io/PyMultiNest/install.html) (under 2. Building the libraries). When I call `cmake ..` I receive an error saying:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
> Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)

I'm not having much luck trying to find out how to fix this. Can anyone break it down real simply for me?

Comment: Install blas to your system. `under 2. Building the libraries` There is also section `2. Prerequisites for building the libraries`. You have to have those "prerequisites".

Comment: @KamilCuk Isn't that what `sudo apt-get install python-{scipy,numpy,matplotlib,progressbar} ipython libblas{3,-dev} liblapack{3,-dev} libatlas{3-base,-dev} cmake build-essential git gfortran` does? I've ran that but replaced python with python3.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 : The prerequisites are `sudo apt install python3-{scipy,numpy,matplotlib,progressbar} ipython3 libblas{3,-dev} liblapack{3,-dev} libatlas-base-dev cmake build-essential git gfortran` ..... I.e. "the year 2017 instructions" are for "old Ubuntu".